# Adding time to an event that runs on a weekly basis

Tags: mysql

I have this event that runs every Thursday

```
CREATE EVENT le_drop_database
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY   
 DO BEGIN
  drop database carbon;
    END */$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I was wondering how i would add some parameter that indicates the time this event should run on Thursday for example run at 11:00 a.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things you should do with this

1. Change `DROP DATABASE` to `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS`
2. Add `INTERVAL 11 HOUR` to the `START` (as mentioned by @ypercube)
3. Add `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` to make it a repeatable event so you don't have to create it again.

Here are the changes

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE EVENT le_drop_database
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY + INTERVAL 11 HOUR DO
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
BEGIN
  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS carbon;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I hope this event is not in the `carbon` database

If you ever need to disable the event, just run

```
ALTER EVENT le_drop_database DISABLE;
```

to reenable

```
ALTER EVENT le_drop_database ENABLE;
```

## CAVEAT

Please make sure you have this in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=1
```

You can enable this without restarting mysql by running

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Le Grand Rolando saved my day.A million thanks.