# Mysql syntax error when i add on completion preserve

Tags: mysql

I have written this event in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE EVENT le_drop_database   
ON SCHEDULE 
   EVERY 1 WEEK         
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE          
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 4 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR_MINUTE DO
BEGIN
   DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS carbon;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but everytime i run it,it says i have a syntax error `right syntax to use near 'STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 4 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY + INTERVAL '10:00' ' at line 5 */`

Line five happens to be `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`.If i delete line 5,the event is added successfully but if i do that the event will not be what i wanted.

Why is it a syntax error yet everything looks fine?.

Comment: Put `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` after the `STARTS` part and add a DO after it.

Comment: I fixed it back in the other post : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75237/877